# An algorithm to segment time-series based on neighbouring values [python]

Tags: python, python-3.x, algorithm

I have multiple time-series or simply lists of integers like below -

```
array([   1,    1,    1,    1,    1,    1,    1,    1,    1,    1,    1,
          1,    1,    1,    1,    1,    1,    1,    1,    1,    1,    1,
          1,   55,   57,   58,   59,   59,   57,   59,   56,   58,   58,
         57,   58,   58,   59,   57,   57,   59,   56,   60,   58,   59,
         55,   59,   60,   56,   57,   60,   56,   59,   56,   58,   58,
         57,   61,   55,   58,   58,   59,   57,   58,   58,   58,   58,
         58,   58,   66,   49,   59,   59,   56,   57,   59,   60,   58,
         56,   57,   60,   56,   60,   55,   59,   59,   56,   59, 3057,
          1,    1,    1,    1,    2,    1,    1,    1,    1,    1,    1,
          1,    1,    1,    1,    1,    1,    1,    1,    1,    1,    1,
          1,   41,   59,   57,   58,   59,   59,   57,   58,   59,   56,
         59,   57,   58,   57,   59,   57,   60,   57,   57,   58,   57,
         58,   58,   57,   58,   64,   52,   58,   59,   59,   55,   58,
         59,   57,   58,   58,   58,   60,   57,   56,   58,   59,   57,
         58,   57,   59,   59,   57, 3055,    2,    1,    1,    1,    1,
          1,    1,    2,    1,    1,    1,    1,    1,    1,    1,    1,
          1,    1,    1,    1,    1], dtype=int64)
```

I am trying to implement a python function which would give me a list of segmented regions from the list as below:

```
[1,    1,    1,    1,    1,    1,    1,    1,    1,    1,    1,
 1,    1,    1,    1,    1,    1,    1,    1,    1,    1,    1,
 1],

[55,   57,   58,   59,   59,   57,   59,   56,   58,   58,
57,   58,   58,   59,   57,   57,   59,   56,   60,   58,   59,
55,   59,   60,   56,   57,   60,   56,   59,   56,   58,   58,
57,   61,   55,   58,   58,   59,   57,   58,   58,   58,   58,
58,   58,   66,   49,   59,   59,   56,   57,   59,   60,   58,
56,   57,   60,   56,   60,   55,   59,   59,   56,   59],

[1,    1,    1,    1,    2,    1,    1,    1,    1,    1,    1,
 1,    1,    1,    1,    1,    1,    1,    1,    1,    1,    1,
 1],
...
```

**Note:** *3057* is not added as it is an outlier and has a length 1 only (this is not mandatory as it can be later filtered based on length easily).

I can think of some ad-hoc logic, but I'm looking for a robust and pythonic approach (the range of values will be within (1,~10000)).

Comment: Can you define 'neighbouring'? What is the logic you're thinking of?

Comment: adjacent elements should be close enough, for example in the first list we see a trend of 1s then suddenly 55, it is a sharp spike, this sudden gradient is the point where the list should be segmented. The sudden change can be defined based on some threshold probably (3-4 times), not sure about that yet.

Comment: This question has been mentioned on Meta: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/396302/6471538

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you have not defined what you want "different" to be I have left it as a function

```
def diff(x, y):
    return np.abs(x-y) > 20

np.split(ary, np.argwhere(diff(ary[1:], ary[:-1])).T[0] + 1)
```

Comment: this doesn't work. For example, after replacing 20 with 5, running it on `segment(np.array([1,0,1,1,2,21,20,19,5,12,51,40]))` - I get, `[array([1, 0, 1, 1, 2]),
 array([21, 20, 19]),
 array([5]),
 array([12]),
 array([51]),
 array([40])]`, this is wrong segmentation according to criteria.

Comment: You added no criteria - that is the whole point; rewrite diff to what you want then

Comment: First of all, I think you didn't understand the question completely. Secondly, even if I consider your code and your diff (the absolute difference of value between adjacent elements > constant), it doesn't split the array based on your own criteria.

Comment: in case you missed the comment, *adjacent elements should be close enough, for example in the first list we see a trend of 1s then suddenly 55, it is a sharp spike, this sudden gradient is the point where the list should be segmented. The sudden change can be defined based on some threshold probably (3-4 times), not sure about that yet.*

Comment: If I did not understand the question please explain how; I have provided an algorithm to split a numpy array based on a generic difference function which acts on adjacent elements. By definition this fits my own criteria. Your comment is not a part of the question; if it is critical to the question then edit your post, it is simple to change the diff flag to act in this way.

Comment: Okay, I got to fix the issues by adding some more constraints. Accepting your answer for now.